# What solutions do you use to host html prototypes for your clients

Tags: password, prototype

I have been using a basic hosting service to host html prototypes for clients. I have realized that I need a solution that can offer me greater control e.g. to allow me to set master passwords for all prototypes.

I wondered what solutions other use for this purpose?

Comment: Are you looking for a service like [OneHub](https://onehub.com/)?

Comment: Closing this post as it's just a shopping recommendations question and there is no correct answer to this.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Handcraft](http://handcraft.com/):

> Handcraft is a collaborative HTML prototyping tool built for interactivity and precise control.

It does exactly what you want (although passwords are set on a per-prototype basis):

> - Prototypes live at [yourprototype].handcraft.com and can be protected by a password of your choosing.
> - Easily share prototypes with colleagues and work on code together without fear of losing your changes.
> - Your work is automatically backed up. Change history of all your prototypes means you'll never lose your work.
> - We take care of the loose ends so your clients always get a smooth experience.

(Disclaimer: I make Handcraft.)

Comment: <ahem> http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/626/community-promotion-ads-2012

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to take business away from Rahul! but in the past I've used [Axure](http://www.axure.com/interactiveprototypes). The prototypes created are fully executable, inheriting all the behaviours you've discussed with the client like interactive navigation, popups/lightboxes and simulation of the shopping basket experience.

When generating your prototype, there are some nice export configuration options like displaying notes only for the client and the viewport tag, which allows you to show your UI on mobile devices.

However securing the prototypes means using [AxShare](http://share.axure.com/). This means exporting a RP file. Sharing is free though!

Comment: That's not really a HTML prototype hosting service though; it's an Axure prototype hosting service that will transform the output from Axure RP into HTML just so it'll run in the browser

Comment: While Axure spits out HTML, it's really not HTML in any sense of the word that a person that writes HTML would use. ;)

Comment: @DA01 I didn't want to go there, so thanks for taking care of that ;-)

Comment: Agree with DA01 you're not going to ship it, but it might be quicker bashing out exectuable prototypes to clients that some of time have throw away parts. I also agree, check your hosting control panel. They might have some way to password protect on a per-directory basis.

Answer (score 0):

Most any basic hosting service these days has a control panel admin interface that should let you set passwords on a per-directory basis.